# Materialized view not refreshing

Tags: oracle, materialized-views

I have the following scenario:

I have created 2 tables in custom schema in 11.5.10. I have created a materialized view in a new schema(not apps) in 11.5.9 joining the 2 tables in 11.5.10

I have used following syntax for creating a MV

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW <new_schema>.xx_sample_testing_mv 
REFRESH NEXT SYSDATE+1/1440
as 
select...........
```

When I add new records to the 2 tables materialized view is not getting refreshed.
When I create materialized view only on a single table its getting refreshed, but not when I use more than one table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should check the following points:

- You specified refresh period as 1 minutes(1/1440 day = 1 min). Is the materialized view refreshed after 1 minute?
- Try to execute the select part and it is finished running in 1 minute.

Comment: Hi ntalbs,Here i created view logs to each base table for capturing data purpose.Can I use single materialized view for those two base tables?

Comment: Yes. Perhaps you should read this article. http://www.sqlsnippets.com/en/topic-12922.html

Comment: Thanks ntlabs.The article some what helped for me

Answer (score 0):

Check are there any blocking sessions or locked objects in the database.
Check how many sessions are active and inactive for the owner of the MV using below query and if they are running for longer period then get approval from the application owner and kill the sessions and trigger the refresh again.

select sid,username,status,module,last_call_et,logon_time from v$session where username='DEMO' order by LAST_CALL_ET desc;